# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity - even when it was

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jpaDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.domain</value>
            <value>com.example.repositories</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have my Geoname class in com.example.domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="geonames")
public class Geoname implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="geonameid")
    private Long geonameid = null;
}
```

yet, when running, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified
>   for entity: com.example.domain.Geoname    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:664)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3449)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3403)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1330)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1730)

Any ideas why?

side note: I am combining both mongodb and hibernate/ mysql on this project.

Comment: Is the Id annotation the one from the `javax.persistence` package?

Comment: can u show the import

Answer (score 252, accepted):

I had the following

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

Naturally, it should be:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

Thanks to @JB Nizet

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same error.I solved it and figured out i didn't put @Id annotations in id field in my Entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="geonames")
public class Geoname implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="geonameid")
    private Long geonameid = null;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
  @Column(name="geonameid",unique=true,nullable=false)
```

Comment: Can you please remove the answer, also you are going to get back your points :)