# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource.No identifier specified for entity:

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:

Comment: can you please provide full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you add the `entity` class code? Based on the error it is expecting an `@Id` member in the entity class

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
In my case,its because of wrong @Id annotation import.
It should be :- import javax.persistence.Id;

ref:-(https://stackoverflow.com/a/15323836/19262829)